# Laravel: download string with dompdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf

i am using dompdf in laravel and my code is:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('test_pdf');  
return $pdf->download('medium.pdf');
```

in this code is view is loaded.
if I want to download a string for example "test test" without using view, what should i do?

I tried

```
$pdf = 'test test';  
return $pdf->download('medium.pdf');
```

but get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('test_pdf');  
return $pdf->download('medium.pdf');
```